# Transform XML to HTML table

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I want to transform xml to html using xsl but I'm struggling to make it work although it should be pretty straightforward.

Input XML:

```html
<EEExport Version="201510" Language="International" LanguageIsoCode="int-INT">
  <Navigation>
    <Navigation Name="Navigation" NavigationID="E905C889-63EF-431E-BD74-A470685F65E0">
      <Navigation Name="Oven" NavigationID="B929861A-57D1-4C20-BE2C-0DC006F4D6CE">
      </Navigation>
      <Navigation Name="Cooker" NavigationID="643B0A58-D83B-4D8F-9E97-A5C8E572B1E5">
      </Navigation>
      <Navigation Name="Dishwasher" NavigationID="FAB9B544-109D-4B83-A6E4-25114E1D25BA">
        <Product ProductID="887B5B3C-F9C7-4F4A-8E0B-1FC62830C508">
          <MasterData>
            <Brand>Brand1</Brand>
            <ProductCode>911 424 310</ProductCode>
            <Category ID="B1679547-77B2">Dish_Washer</Category>
          </MasterData>
          <Containers>
            <Container ContainerName="STechSpec_Dish_Washer">
              <Attribute AttributeID="36214A61" Name="ModelD" >F55600IM0P</Attribute>
              <Attribute AttributeID="C3C36430" Name="BarCode" >7332543317288</Attribute>
              <Attribute AttributeID="0B38C70E" Name="CutleryShelves" >None</Attribute>
          </Container>
        </Containers>
      </Product>
      <Product ProductID="D4DB8281-42D7-4240-8731-220FD728481D">
          <MasterData>
            <Brand>Brand2</Brand>
            <ProductCode>911 536 090</ProductCode>
            <Category ID="B1679547-77B2">Dish_Washer</Category>
          </MasterData>
          <Containers>
            <Container ContainerName="STechSpec_Dish_Washer">
              <Attribute AttributeID="36214A61" Name="ModelD" >ZDT26020FA</Attribute>
              <Attribute AttributeID="C3C36430" Name="BarCode" >7332543397303</Attribute>
              <Attribute AttributeID="0B38C70E" Name="CutleryShelves" >Cutlery Drawer</Attribute>
            </Container>
          </Containers>
        </Product>
      </Navigation>
    </Navigation>
  </Navigation>
</EEExport>
```

I only want to show specific product fields of category 'Dishwasher'.
Desired output:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#e3e3e3">
        <th>Brand</th>
        <th>Product Code</th>
        <th>Model D</th>
        <th>Cutlery Shelves</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brand1</td>
        <td>911 424 310</td>
        <td>F55600IM0P</td>
        <td>None</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brand2</td>
        <td>911 536 090</td>
        <td>ZDT26020FA</td>
        <td>Cutlery Drawer</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Current xsl:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#e3e3e3">
        <th>Brand</th>
        <th>Product Code</th>
        <th>Model D</th>
        <th>Cutlery Shelves</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="/EEExport/Navigation/Navigation/Navigation[@Name='Dishwasher']/Product">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="/Masterdata/Brand"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="/Masterdata/ProductCode"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="/Containers/Container/Attribute[@Name='ModelD']"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="/Containers/Container/Attribute[@Name='CutleryShelves']"/></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your XSLT.

Firstly, when you start an XPath expression with `/` then this represents the top-level document node, and so the search will be relative to that, and not to the node you are currently positioned on.

So instead of doing this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/Masterdata/Brand"/>
```

Do this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Masterdata/Brand"/>
```

Having said that, this leads on to the second issue. XML and XSLT are case sensitive. In your XML you use `MasterData`, but in your XSLT you refer to `Masterdata`. So, the expression should actually be like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="MasterData/Brand"/>
```

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#e3e3e3">
        <th>Brand</th>
        <th>Product Code</th>
        <th>Model D</th>
        <th>Cutlery Shelves</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="EEExport/Navigation/Navigation/Navigation[@Name='Dishwasher']/Product">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="MasterData/Brand"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="MasterData/ProductCode"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Containers/Container/Attribute[@Name='ModelD']"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Containers/Container/Attribute[@Name='CutleryShelves']"/></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```